Make DATEDIFF() compatible with clock changes
In the UK, as part of daylight time savings, the clocks go forward by one hour at 1AM on the last Sunday in March which in 2024 was the 31st March
The clocks effectively tick as follows:
2024-03-31T00:59:58
2024-03-31T00:59:59
2024-03-31T00:02:00
2024-03-31T00:02:01

is there a way I can make the DATEDIFF function aware of this?
if I do SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'2024-03-31T00:59:59','2024-03-31T02:01:01') it returns 62, rather than 2
Similarly, if I use the following to convert a UTC time to local time:
SELECT DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), '2024-03-31T00:59:59Z')  AS ColumnInLocalTime
SELECT DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), '2024-03-31T02:01:01Z')  AS ColumnInLocalTime

(taken from the accepted answer to this question)
It uses the current time offset to convert the UTC date to local date rather than the time offset as at the time of the date we are converting
I assume the only way around these issues would be a custom function that is somehow aware of when the clocks changed?

There's nothing wrong with DATEDIFF or summer time. It's already fully aware. The problem is that the type and other functions you used aren't. The attempt to "convert" the timezone  is wrong.

"is there a way I can make the DATEDIFF function aware of this?" it is aware of this, provided your times have the relevant timezone offset information. SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CONVERT(datetimeoffset(0),'20240331 00:00:00Z'),CONVERT(datetimeoffset(0),'20240331 02:00:00+01:00')) correctly returns 60, for example.

BTW most answers in the question you linked to use AT TIME ZONE, not date arithmetic. The accepted answer uses SWITCHOFFSET to switch offsets. GETDATE() has no offset information though so the database can only assume it's local time in the server's timezone. If the server is at UTC instead of British time, like most cloud-hosted servers, there's no summer time

Alternatively, as @PanagiotisKanavos mentioned, using AT TIME ZONE also works as expected: SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CONVERT(datetime2(0),'20240331 00:00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'GMT Standard Time',CONVERT(datetime2(0),'20240331 02:00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'GMT Standard Time')

UTC isn't the same as UK time. UTC is the base against which all other times are calculated and its offset is always 9. Z is a shortcut for this. In the summer the UK is 1 hour ahead of UTC and matches UTC in the winter

The real problem will be when the clocks go back. Was 2023-10-29T01:30:00 2023-10-29T01:30:00+01:00 or 2023-10-29T01:30:00+00:00? Unless you store that information, you have no way of knowing.

Works fine for me with datetimeoffset https://dbfiddle.uk/h3vVy8Zj that's assuming you saved the offset. If you haven't then I wish you luck... as mentioned you can't always assume the offset after you saved just the date and time.

Use AT TIME ZONE function to provide timezone offset to your DATETIME values and convert them to DATETIMEOFFSET:
SELECT DATEDIFF( MINUTE, CONVERT( datetime, '2024-03-31T00:59:59') AT TIME ZONE 'GMT Standard Time',
    CONVERT( datetime, '2024-03-31T02:01:01' ) AT TIME ZONE 'GMT Standard Time' )
-- Output: 2

This function relies on Windows to do the conversions.
